# Como forçar o download de um arquivo, que esta armazenado no banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Tenho um sistema onde, são listados documentos do banco de dados, onde o usuário tem a opção de visualizar ou baixar o arquivo. Quero saber como faço para resgatar este arquivo do banco e forçar o download dele. Este arquivo está em `.pdf`

Este é o codigo que eu tenho

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");

//pega o arquivo 
$sql_select_file = "SELECT * FROM malote_arq_2014 WHERE reg=" . $reg . "";
$query_select_file = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_select_file);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query_select_file);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$arquivo);
```

Só que ele me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

**Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in**

Comment: Já viu esse artigo? http://blog.thiagobelem.net/forcando-o-download-de-arquivos-com-php/

Comment: Sim, e já testei aquele script, mas ele continua me retornando mesma mensagem que citei acima

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 já que você conseguiu resolver e era um erro bem específico, eu sugeriria deletar a pergunta neste caso.

Comment: @Bacco, eu realmente estava confundindo o nome do arquivo com o conteúdo. No 'header' eu estava passando o conteúdo do arquivo, experimentei colocar um nome qualquer, e funcionou. Problema resolvido!

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 ótimo. Ainda acho que seria o caso de deletar a pergunta, mas veja o que acha melhor! O importante é que resolveu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente `$arquivo` está vindo com caracteres especiais ao final.

Experimente usando a função `trim` para limpar estes caracteres:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".trim( $arquivo) );
```

Esta solução é melhor como meio apenas de identificar o problema, pois o ideal seria o nome do arquivo já ser originariamente capturado sem nenhum caractere desnecessário.

Experimente também comentar estas linhas:

```
// header("Content-type: application/pdf");
...
// header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$arquivo);
```

e colocar no final um `print_r( $arquivo );` para identificar outros enganos.

> Certifique-se também de não estar colocando o **conteúdo do arquivo** no lugar do **nome do arquivo**.

Comment: continua dando a mesma mensagem de erro

Comment: será que pelo fato de eu omitir o tamanho do arquivo, seja o motivo deste erro?

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 experimente a sugestao que eu pus para vermos o que se encontra em $arquivo. Desconfio que tenha algo errado lá. Se não for isso, pode ter problemas em outra parte do código. Seria bom você por o código completo, ou ao menos a parte que cria a variável `$arquivo`.

Comment: Utilizei o sua sugestão, ele me mostra uma porção de caracteres, que são ilegíveis. E creio que não seja erro no código, pois utilizo este mesmo código para exibir o arquivo, no browser

Comment: consegui, foi exatamente isso o que você disse, estava passando para o header o conteudo do arquivo. Experimentei colocar o nome, e funcionou